# Docker Compose and Django generator syntax error

Tags: python, django, docker

I'm new to Docker and have been trying to set up Django with Docker. I've been following the instructions  [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/) but am running into the error down below.

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site- 
  packages/django/contrib/admin/widgets.py", line 152
  web_1  |     '%s=%s' % (k, v) for k, v in params.items(),
  web_1  |     ^
  web_1  | SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized
```

My Django version is 2.1, Python 3.7. As far as I know, this shouldn't be happening, yet it is. I have checked the file in question, and it is written correctly. It was a fix that was put into place that should have fixed this error in the past with the latest version of Python.

**EDIT** Adding Docker file here:

```
 FROM python:3
 ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
 RUN mkdir /code
 WORKDIR /code
 ADD requirements.txt /code/
 RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
 ADD . /code/
```

docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
  web:
    build: .
    command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

From widgets.py:

```
if params:
            related_url += '?' + '&amp;'.join('%s=%s' % (k, v) for k, v in params.items())
```

This is the entire definition form widgets.py:

```
def get_context(self, name, value, attrs):
    context = super().get_context(name, value, attrs)
    rel_to = self.rel.model
    if rel_to in self.admin_site._registry:
        # The related object is registered with the same AdminSite
        related_url = reverse(
            'admin:%s_%s_changelist' % (
                rel_to._meta.app_label,
                rel_to._meta.model_name,
            ),
            current_app=self.admin_site.name,
        )

        params = self.url_parameters()
        if params:
            related_url += '?' + '&amp;'.join('%s=%s' % (k, v) for k, v in params.items())
        context['related_url'] = mark_safe(related_url)
        context['link_title'] = _('Lookup')
        # The JavaScript code looks for this class.
        context['widget']['attrs'].setdefault('class', 'vForeignKeyRawIdAdminField')
    if context['widget']['value']:
        context['link_label'], context['link_url'] = self.label_and_url_for_value(value)
    return context
```

However, I still get the same error code when trying to compose-up.

I have no idea what to do at this point; I'm at a complete loss. This is the first time I've run into this problem.

Comment: Which Django version are you using?

Comment: Try your Django version with Python 3.6!

Comment: I don't think you have Django 2.1 installed (maybe you have a separate virtualenv?). Note that in the error message there is an extra comma (`,`) after `params.items()` while in the actual source there isn't. That comma was removed in Django 2.0 (see https://github.com/django/django/commit/931c60c5216bd71bc11f489e00e063331cf21f40)

Comment: Is it possible that you messed something up when creating your container? Post any relevant Docker files you used.

Comment: @Selcuk I've checked my version and it is Django 2.1. That said, I completely understand what you're saying. I haven't run this under a virtual environment. Is there a way to check if my system is pointing to the wrong Django version? How can I check if I have multiple versions installed?

Comment: We are talking about the Django inside the Docker container, right? What does your `requirements.txt` say? That tutorial you linked has `Django>=1.8,<2.0`, which is **not** compatible with Python 3.7.

Comment: @Selcuk Yes, I changed that to Django>=2.0

Comment: @Nathan, did you solve this? I have the same bug following the quickstart [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/#connect-the-database). Strange thing is, that if I use ` FROM python:3.6` it still runs `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/` and if I do `Django>=2.0` I still get the error message.

Comment: I havent solved it for 3.7, unfortunately. I still consider this an open issue for me, even though I did get it working another way.

The only other way I could get it working is to have python 3.6 installed, and start a virtual environment that only uses python 3.6. Then, docker will work with django just fine.

Answer (score 3):

First of all

> Your Django version is not compatible with Python 3.7

So make these changes

In your Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.6
```

Restart docker using `sudo service docker restart`

then `sudo docker-compose up --build`

or 
`sudo docker-compose run web python manage.py migrate` and `sudo docker-compose up --build`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to run sample from **byob-profiles-rest-api**.

- This example is pretty old and you have to down grade your versions:

Change your Django version to 1.11 to avoid error

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.core.urlresolvers'

Change your Python version to 3.6

> SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized

- You files should now look like this

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.6

ENV PYTHONBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
COPY . /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

**requirements.txt**

```
appdirs==1.4.3
Django==1.11
djangorestframework==3.6.2
packaging==16.8
pyparsing==2.2.0
pytz==2017.2
six==1.10.0
```

- Delete the old image of byob-profiles-rest-api
- Recreate the image by running

> docker-compose run web python src/profiles_project/manage.py migrate

You should see that there's no more errors.

```
Running migrations:    
Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK   
Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK   
Applying auth.0001_initial... OK   
Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK   
Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK   
Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK   
Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK   
Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... OK   
Applying auth.0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages... OK   
Applying auth.0008_alter_user_username_max_length... OK   
Applying profiles_api.0001_initial... OK   
Applying admin.0001_initial... OK   
Applying admin.0002_logentry_remove_auto_add... OK   
Applying authtoken.0001_initial... OK   
Applying authtoken.0002_auto_20160226_1747... OK   
Applying profiles_api.0002_profilefeeditem... OK   
Applying sessions.0001_initial... OK
```

- Build and start the server

> sudo docker-compose up --build